# Breakdown of absentee vs. in-person voting in the 2016 presidential primary

Tags: elections, politics

I am looking for the breakdown of the 2016 presidential primary results on the state or lower level by absentee, early, and in-person voting. I've found a few resources that have aggregated primary results, but none of these seem to touch on early or absentee voting:

- the [US election atlas](http://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/). There are a few [paid data sources](http://uselectionatlas.org/BOTTOM/store_data.php) on the website, but none of them mention anything about absentee/early voting in their descriptions.
- [openelections](http://docs.openelections.net/metadata-api/). They don't seem to have aggregated 2016 data yet, and again, no mention of absentee/early voting.

I've also looked at a few previous results ([(1)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/619/sources-of-political-voting-records-at-the-county-level), [(2)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6583/where-can-i-find-data-on-the-winner-of-the-presidential-popular-vote-by-u-s-cou)) that suggest that it's hard to find a centralized source for any of this information. I'm just surprised that I haven't been able to find absentee vs. early vs. in-person information for *any* state. Is this required information for a state to report? Should I be looking elsewhere on their sites? Has anyone (fingers crossed) aggregated this yet?

**Edit:** It looks like TargetSmart offers this commercially in their [VoterBase](http://targetsmart.com/offering/voterbase/) (found via [this article](http://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/what-does-early-vote-say-about-who-will-do-well-n543641)).